# Flutter debugging

Tags: flutter, debugging

I'm trying to debug my app. I've been most of the pages but sometimes when it get to some pages, the debugging page breaks and takes me to the file but does not show exactly where the error is. What does this mean?

Comment: Can you provide more information, or maybe a screenshot of what you're getting? It can come from an exception that occurred in your code for instance.

Comment: Emmm, the code is really big (1187 lines). I don't know exactly where the break is from. I would gladly send it if I did. The code actually works well when I'm not debugging. It only break at that page when I'm debugging

Comment: Do you use visual studio code or android studio for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

In case you use Visual Studio Code for debugging.

If there's no error log show in your terminal/debug console. Then there must be breakpoints dot, i believe you accidentally clicked breakpoint red dot in any line of your code. You can check it left menu Run and Debug, then at the bottom of section there is Breakpoints. The default setting, vscode checked the "All Exceptions" and "Uncaught Exceptions" item, besides that, you added your self to breakpoints, uncheck all item beside the default or you can remove it from breakpoints by click the X icon.

Heres a picture to help navigate you.

[image]

Comment: No. That's not it. When dubuging and there is an error, the debugger shows exactly where the error is and I solve it. 
The problem is with one particular page. On this page the debugger showed me several errors and I corrected them. But then after correcting them when I continue to debug that page breaks(even after correcting all that errors), then takes me to the code page(where I've already done the debugging) but does not show where the error occured